# How to configure manifest.json with create react app and webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I am working on `react-boilerplate`. And I also have configured webpack with but after integrating webpack I am getting error which is related to `manifest.json`.

```
Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
```

To fix this, I am using `webpack-pwa-manifest` and configured `webpack.config.js` 
https://github.com/arthurbergmz/webpack-pwa-manifest

```
const manifest = new WebpackPwaManifest({
  name: 'React Starter Kit',
  short_name: 'React Starter Kit',
  description: 'React Starter Kit',
  background_color: '#ffffff',
  start_url: '/',
  scope: '/',
  theme_color: "#3367D6",
  icons: [
    {
      src: path.resolve('public/images/icons/icon-512x512.png'),
      sizes: [96, 128, 192, 256, 384, 512] // multiple sizes
    },
    {
      src: path.resolve('public/images/icons/icon-512x512.png'),
      size: '1024x1024' // you can also use the specifications pattern
    }
  ]
})
```

looking ideal way to handle this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using HtmlWebpackPlugin as well? 
Manifest should be injected automatically,
make sure you don't have any manually added manifest link 
in your html template.